# What is ...DirectiveName mean in angular 2

Tags: angular

What is `...DirectiveName` mean in angular 2

Exp: `[...ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]`

When I use only  `[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]` it still work, Why we add ... before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself, ... is Spread syntax.
Example:

```
var parts = ['shoulders', 'knees'];
var lyrics = ['head', ...parts, 'and', 'toes']; // ["head", "shoulders", "knees", "and", "toes"]
```

See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

And angular 2 understand both of it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer but I will try to explain to you with my code I used in my shopping cart component. ROUTER_DIRECTIVES use "router-outlet" to display any of the routes: Electronic, Video, but the rest of the components remains the same in terms of display in the ".html". Below is the partial code of my component. Hopefully this helps and not to confuse you. Happy coding.

```
@Component({
  module: moduleId,
  selector: 'rb-shopping',
  templateUrl: 'shopping.component.html,
  directives: [FeaturedBrand, SubCategory, ProductList, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@Routes([
  { path: 'e', component: ElectronicsComponent },
  { path: 'v', component: VideoGamesComponent },
  { path: '/', DefaultComponent}
])
//my shopping.html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<rb-subcategories [input]="searchStr"></rb-sub-categories>
<rb-featured-brands [input]="searchStr"></rb-featured-brands>
<rb-product-list [input]="searchStr"></rb-product-list>
```